# why doesn't get xml nodeValue in javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml

```
if (window.DOMParser) {
    parser=new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(txt,"text/xml");
}
else { // Internet Explorer 
    xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.async="false";
    xmlDoc.loadXML(txt); 
}
                /*copy ends*/
temp = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('COMMENT');
s0 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('TITLE')[i].nodeValue;
s1 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('CMT')[i].nodeValue;
```

s0 and s1 returned null and i dont understand why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `nodeValue` property of XML elements is always `null`, because the element content is actually stored within text nodes inside the element. If the content is simple enough, you can do something like:

```
s0 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
s1 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CMT")[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
```