# Returning XML node values

Tags: javascript, xml

I need to return all XML values from a URL.

I have previously used the URL and it works fine.

This is what I have so far:

```
function displayXML(xml) {
        var devices = xml.getElementsByTagName("device");

        for (var i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
            var deviceDetails = devices[i].children;

            for (j = 0; j < deviceDetails.length; j++) {
                console.log(devices[i].childNodes[j].nodeValue);
            }

        }


    }
```

It manages to return the right amount of values: 33 tags 33 values

but it's returning null for each one. However, the XML file contains values for each tag.

Thanks

Comment: Hey, if the answer below helped you please mark as accepted answer.

Comment: Regarding [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45935708/1218980), please do not delete your questions without a valid reason, it might be useful to someone in the future and this is what makes SO quality so high.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on an answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056305/why-doesnt-get-xml-nodevalue-in-javascript)

The `nodeValue` property of XML elements is always null. The value of the element is actually stored within text nodes inside the element so you will need to go down one more child to get it. Try this

```
var devices = xml.getElementsByTagName("device")[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
```

I think your script should look something like this with `firstChild` inserted when trying to get the value:

```
function displayXML(xml) {
        var devices = xml.getElementsByTagName("device");

        for (var i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
            var deviceDetails = devices[i].children;

            for (j = 0; j < deviceDetails.length; j++) {
                console.log(devices[i].childNodes[j].firstChild.nodeValue);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: @KieranMelia Awesome, glad to hear it. Not sure if you seen my updated answer but i think my changes to your script should work although its untested so far.